# Python Flask: accessing one particular dictionary item in the template

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I have one static `dictionary`:

```
urls = {
    'foo': 'http://example.com',
    'bar': 'http://example2.com',
    'test': 'http://example3.com'}
```

Then I have a list of tuples. Each `tuple` contains one key of the previous dictionary:

```
myList = [('bar', 0.9),('test', 0.7),('foo', 0.5)]
```

I want to put in my template the related url for each key string in the descending order as they are in the list (created [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value) obviously with the `reverse = True` set).

In the template I have tried this, but, as expected, it doesn't work:

```
{% for i in myList %}
<tr>
<a href= " {{ urls[i[0]] }} ">  
  <td>
    {{ i[0] }}
  </td> 
</a> 
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So, how can I access the `dictionary` elements?

Comment: What error are you getting and what's your `render_template` code looking like?

Comment: no errors, simply the hyperlinks are not working, i have just text

Comment: I can't see your dictionary is well formed. I've initialized it like this: `urls = {
    'foo': 'http://example.com',
    'bar': 'http://example2.com',
    'test': 'http://example.com',
}`

Comment: you are right, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resulting HTML is wrong.

Don't put table elements into your link text the way you do it.

I've tested plain html like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <a href= " http://google.de ">
      <td> Fooo 
      </td>
    </a>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and it will result in a "dead" link. Put the full `a href` into your `<td>` instead:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <a href= " http://google.de ">
        Fooo 
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: About as useful as "The code you said doesn't work? It doesn't work."

Comment: Hi, my mistake, your solution is right. But I did not downvote you, as a matter of fact I have not enough reputation. Checkmark for you instead

Comment: No, all is fine with you. It was @AdamSmith who is quite fast downvoting someone despite he is actually refining his answer though. Nevermind... I shouldn't have answered incompletely in the first run not to be bashed.

Comment: @ferdy well you answered, then deleted, then edited your deleted answer, then undeleted, then FURTHER edited into a *real* answer. I've now removed my downvote.

Comment: @AdamSmith, thank you. Well, I edited the deleted answer because the system said I should preferably edit the old answer instead of creating a new one. So, because in the first answer I got the question completely wrong, I didn't want to have it on the screen for too long, so I did a preview of the final answer. That was the "genesis" of this  thing. All right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  "| safe " as follows:

```
    {% for i in myList %}
    <tr>
    <a href= " {{ urls[i[0]] | safe }} ">  
      <td>
        {{ i[0] }}
      </td> 
    </a> 
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work, same situation as before